# SAP GATEWAY & UI5: How can reset the CSRF token?=

Tags: sapui5, abap, sap-gateway

I need to reset the CSRF token in an OData model. Based on the UI5 documentation I am trying to do that with `refreshSecurityToken(fnSuccess?, fnError?, bAsync?)` function. ([click here for reference](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.44.15/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel.html#refreshSecurityToken))

I wrote the following code:

```
var oDataModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("ZMDM_ODATA_FILE_SRV");
    oDataModel.setTokenHandlingEnabled(true);
    oDataModel.refreshSecurityToken(function() {
        var token = oDataModel.getSecurityToken();
        console.log(token);
        // can upload the file if token reset
    });
```

The problem is that this token is not reset for 30 minutes and that is our session timeout. Actually it is valid during the session lifetime. I even checked the following link:

https://blogs.sap.com/2014/08/26/gateway-protection-against-cross-site-request-forgery-attacks/

Actually many people had this problem, but I couldn't find a clear solution for resetting the token. I did all the required steps in the front-end for the sending a Head request for resting the token. I think something is missing regarding the back-end gateway settings or ABAP coding.

What do I have to do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

seems like you need to set a interval in your front-end application to fetch and update the token more often. But that's a paradox: if your back-end sets the timeout for 30 minutes, why would you keep it live for more time?

SecurityToken timeout is important to make sure the active session is being used and that no individual "forgot" it and left the system open and unwatched/unused.

But if you really need to keep your front-end session always available and force the back-end to be too, you can setInterval() to fetch the CSRF and update the application:

```
var oDataModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("ZMDM_ODATA_FILE_SRV");
oDataModel.setTokenHandlingEnabled(true);
var fnRefreshToken = oDataModel.refreshSecurityToken(function() {
    var token = oDataModel.getSecurityToken();
    console.log(token);
    // can upload the file if token reset
});
window.setInterval(function(){
    fnRefreshToken;
}, 1800000); // where 1.800.000 miliseconds represents 30 minutes
```

And then you should store your new token in the token variable and allow upload if token is reset.

Kindly regards,
Henrique Mattos

Answer (score 0):

You can delete a CSRF Token (per user/token) via transaction SM05.

Comment: I will check it. Any other function modules for resetting the CSRF token and not delete?

Comment: What do you mean by resetting? Why do you want to reset the token exactly?

Comment: It needs to be reset to be able to send a new file to CMS.

Comment: No it doesnt need to be reset for each call of abap method CREATE_STREAM. You can reuse your tokens. If your backend doesnt accept the token you just generated, something else is wrong.